# PCI passthrough device memory access incorrect

Tags: memory, virtual-machine, kvm, pci-passthrough

I have a wrlinux yocto system running on an Intel Haswell processor. Here we pass through a PCIe device (broadcom switch) to the VM, launched using qemu/kvm. The Guest is able to detect the device via config space and is allocating memory space based on BAR, but the device memory access seems incorrect. Perhaps the Guest Physical address mapping went wrong? Access doesn't fail, it returns invalid data. How to debug whether the DMA remapping to guest is properly setup or not?